# JavaFX Builder 1.0 unable to open a file

Tags: java, image, javafx, fxml

I get the following error when I try to open a .fxml file from Netbeans:

```
StaffRota.fxml:101: error: 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

the code I have in that xml is:

```xml
<ImageView id="image1.jpg" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="18.0">
      <image>
        <Image url="/theatre/room/allocation/src/misc/image1.jpg" preserveRatio="true" smooth="true" />
      </image>
</ImageView>`
```

My java application builds and deploys fine (and renders the image correctly). Why would JavaFX builder complain? Is it because the image is within the application?

Here's what I get if I do `-tvf tra.jar`:-

```
C:\Users\..\Documents>jar -tvf tra.jar
     0 Mon Jun 17 19:54:26 BST 2013 META-INF/
   425 Mon Jun 17 19:54:26 BST 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Mon Jun 17 19:54:26 BST 2013 theatre/
     0 Mon Jun 17 19:54:26 BST 2013 theatre/room/
     0 Mon Jun 17 19:54:26 BST 2013 theatre/room/allocation/
  .. 
  2563 Mon Jun 17 19:54:26 BST 2013 theatre/room/allocation/src/misc/image1.jpg
  ..
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am new to stackoverflow. I have edited my post to show what I get when I do a `-tvf tra.jar`. Does it help?

Comment: Indeed. Can you replicate it on your side?

Comment: i have fixed it by changing image url to `@../src/misc/image1.jpg`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)  You should enter that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing the url to  `@../src/misc/image1.jpg`